# discord opus problems

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm creating a music bot and i have the error `An error occurred: Command raised an exception: OpusNotLoaded:`

i have already tried do to something like `discord.opus.load_opus("opus")`
but i have the error:
`OSError: dlopen(opus, 6): image not found`

startup of my bot

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as:\n{0.user.name}\n{0.user.id}'.format(bot))
    discord.opus.load_opus("opus")
```

Comment: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/783 did you install the library?

Comment: just installed and it work boy now when i try to play something i have the error 
`ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/783
you need to install the opus library and the ffmpeg library.

Comment: If this answered your question feel free to hit the check mark for answered